# How to configure spring integration consumer to be event driven?

Tags: java, spring, jms, publish-subscribe, spring-integration

How to configure spring integration to use message driven consumer.
With the following configuration, my consumers are polling the messages and i can'f figure out how to make it event driven not polling..

```
 <bean id="dataQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg name="name" value="${jms.data.queue.name}" />
    </bean>

    <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter channel="dataInputChannel" destination="dataQueue"  />
    <int:channel id="dataInputChannel" />    
    <int:channel id="persistDataChannel" />
    <int:channel id="processDataChannel" />

    <int:recipient-list-router id="customRouter" input-channel="dataInputChannel" timeout="10000" ignore-send-failures="true" apply-sequence="true">
        <int:recipient channel="persistDataChannel"/>
        <int:recipient channel="processDataChannel"/>
    </int:recipient-list-router>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean; it *is* event-driven. The thread blocks in the client library's code until a message arrives, or a receive timeout occurs. If you are concerned about the activity seen under TRACE debug by the underlying listener container, simply increase its receiveTimeout.

Comment: What I think he means by Event driven is the JMS driver is probably not using NIO Networking (aka Netty/Grizzly).

Comment: Well, that's in the realm of your provider, not Spring - which is just a JMS client invoking their code.

Comment: Of course. I didn't say you were wrong. Who knows what the OP really meant :)